# How do i grab this string from this large text ?

Tags: php

I have this HTML content..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="pageImpressionID" content="8d0c0cc6-93b3-4d6e-a8c0-9d4552c6d1db" />
 <meta name="pageKey" content="uas-oauth2-auth-code-authorize" >
 <meta name="analyticsURL" content="/analytics/noauthtracker" />
 //.......... Lot more
```

I need to grab `8d0c0cc6-93b3-4d6e-a8c0-9d4552c6d1db` from it. I tried `strip_tags` but all data was stripped off. Any ideas ?

Comment: double split or regex, what have you tried

Comment: You'll probably need to parse the HTML, or use some regex that will probably break and be very hard to make right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DOM parser such as [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/dom) to extract the required data. Here's how you do it:

- Get all the `<meta>` tags using `getElementsByTagName()`
- Loop through them and check if the `name` attribute of the tag is `pageImpressionID`
- If it is, simply echo the `content` attribute

Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('name') === 'pageImpressionID') {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8d0c0cc6-93b3-4d6e-a8c0-9d4552c6d1db
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just search the string for

```
<meta name="pageImpressionID" content="
```

and then copy from that position + 39 (the number of characters in the search string) up to the next apostrophe